# How to handle this simple auto layout issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image: views arranged in portrait orientation][image: views arranged in landscape orientation]

This seems like it should be a simple auto layout issue, but I'm not sure how to handle it. Pictured is the top-level view structure. The yellow show appear on top in portrait (or portrait upside down). It should appear on the left in either landscape mode. The magenta view is square and pinned to the bottom, left and right in portrait and top, bottom, and right in landscape. The yellow and magenta will each have their own sets of subviews, but that is not at issue here.

Since self.view is always portrait, there's no difference from self.view's perspective, between portrait and landscape rotated left, except for which way is up, which is no business of self.view.

The simplest solution I can think of is to not use auto layout, but is there a way to do this with auto layout in Xcode (not programmatically)?

Comment: Please ignore the battery indicator and text in the magenta view. In actuality, the battery indicator would move when in landscape. Additionally, the orientation of the magenta view would rotate with the device rotation. I apologize if that was confusion. I was just lazy and simply rotated the first image to create the second.

Comment: In iOS 8, you might be able to use size classes. In iOS 7 and earlier, though, you'd handle this change programmatically.

Comment: Is your deployment target iOS 8 or something earlier?

Comment: I have not even played with iOS 8 yet.

Comment: How about something along these lines?

The magenta view is always touching the lower, right corner.
The yellow view is always touching the upper, left corner.
Those views could be pinned to those edges.
The magenta view has an aspect ratio constraint.
Inequalities can be used somehow to align with the smaller of two lengths, the two lengths being the long edge length and the short edge length.

Comment: Do you need this to work for all devices and screen sizes?

Comment: Yes. I'm not interested in hard coding specific values, if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: So, you want it to work for iPhones and iPads of all sizes, right? If so, I don't think it can be done without code. I don't think this is a "simple" issue.

Comment: I think I need a third view that's used only for auto layout. Pin it to the bottom, to the right, and to the left. Constrain it's aspect ratio to 1:1. Then the magenta view can be pinned to the right and bottom. It is also constrained to equal the left of its superview with a weak priority. It is also constrained to less than or equal to the new view with a stronger priority. I think this will constrain the magenta view to the smaller of its superview and this new view. A similar thing is done with the yellow view. I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: The yellow one would be pinned to top and left and have the following additional constraints: ) H and V size > some arbitrary minimum value (high priority). Right edge aligned with left of magenta view (low priority). Right edge aligned with right of magenta view (even lower priority). Bottom aligned with top of magenta view (low priority). Bottom aligned with bottom of magenta view (even lower priority). So it aligns with top or bottom and left or right of magenta view as long as it has a positive size.

Comment: I've got it working with one change. Instead of one yellow view, there are two: one for the top, one for the left. I couldn't figure out how to make constraints work for just one yellow view. Two views is fine. One will disappear when the other shows up and vice versa. I need to play with it a bit more before posting my solution. The solution did not require the additional view used just for auto layout.